# Will the app receive Broadcast when it's not launched?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

In my project, I have two modules: "app" and "outerscheme". In app, there is a `MainBroadcastReceiver` (extends `Broadcast`). In outerscheme, there is a `MainActivity` (extends `Activity`). The code is as follows:

outerscheme `MainActivity` core code :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.activity: // start SecondActivity in app module by implicit
            Intent activityIntent = new Intent("SecondActivity");
            activityIntent.setData(Uri.parse("SteveqiSecondActivity://"));
            startActivity(activityIntent);
            break;
        case R.id.broadcast: // start MainBroadcastReceiver in app module by implicit
            Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
            broadcastIntent.setAction("Broadcast");
            // add this the app module may be wakeup.
            broadcastIntent.setData(Uri.parse("SteveqiBroadcast://"));
            sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

app `Manifest` core code:

```
     <activity
        android:name="com.twlkyao.myscheme.SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_second"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="SecondActivity" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="SteveqiSecondActivity" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>   
    <receiver android:name="com.twlkyao.myscheme.MainBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="Broadcast" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="SteveqiBroadcast" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Part I:

When click the `R.id.activity` button, the `SecondActivity` in app module is up, so as the app module, at this time click the `R.id.broadcast` button, the `MainBroadcastReceiver` can receive the broadcast, then kill the process of app module, click the `R.id.broadcast` button, the `MainBroadcastReceiver` can receive the broadcast again, and kill app module again, and click the `R.id.broadcast` button  the `MainBroadcastReceiver` can never receive the broadcast.

Part II:

When I remove the line `<data android:scheme="SteveqiBroadcast" />` of the `MainBroadcastReceiver`, and repeat the ***Part I*** steps, the `MainBroadcastReceiver` can never receive the broadcast.

My questions are:

1.Is that the app module must be alive so that `BroadcastReceiver` can receive broadcast?

2.Why the `BroadcastReceiver` may receive broadcast when `<data android:scheme="SteveqiBroadcast" />` exist, and can't receive broadcast when the line not exit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem, it's because of the ROM, I think MIUI restricts the `Broadcast`, I have successfully run the demo on SamSung phone.

Answer (score 1):

My answers for your  questions

1)No need but in case of dynamic Broadcast Receiver your broadcast receiver will be active until **unRegisterReceiver** is called

2)When broadcasting a intent you are setting dada

```
   Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
   broadcastIntent.setAction("Broadcast");
   // add this the app module may be wakeup.
   broadcastIntent.setData(Uri.parse("SteveqiBroadcast://"));//Check this
   sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
```

Inside your Manifest your Intent filter is expecting that data(**SteveqiBroadcast://**) sent through broadcasted intent

```
  <data android:scheme="SteveqiBroadcast" />
```

So if you remove above schema from manifest it wont receive the broadcast.
If you want to receive the broadcast in this condition also then remove

```
  broadcastIntent.setData(Uri.parse("SteveqiBroadcast://"));
```

Comment: Yes, I both remove them, the problem is something related with the ROM.

Answer (score 0):

The application still can receive message from Broadcast if you set **WAKE_LOCK** permission for it:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: I have tried, add the permission, kill app module, use outerscheme module to send broadcast, the app module still can't receive module.